# CROSS JOIN LATERAL dragging down performance

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query and this is the explain: https://explain.depesz.com/s/ctSQ

```
SELECT
    current_day,
    SUM(daily_holdings_eur) as value_eur
FROM (
    SELECT
        DATE(days) AS current_day,
        ts.coin_id,
        GREATEST(0, SUM(ha.value_eur)) AS daily_holdings_eur
    FROM
        GENERATE_SERIES (
            CURRENT_DATE - '2 DAY' :: INTERVAL,
            CURRENT_DATE,
            '1 DAY' :: INTERVAL
        ) days
    LEFT JOIN transaction_summaries ts ON ts.user_id = 1 AND DATE(ts.trade_at) <= days
    CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
        SELECT price_eur * ts.quantity AS value_eur
        FROM historical_data
        WHERE coin_id = ts.coin_id
        ORDER BY DATE(days)<->snapshot_on
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS ha
    GROUP BY days, ts.coin_id
) final
GROUP BY final.current_day
ORDER BY final.current_day
```

as you can see the issue lies in the `FROM historical_data`.

what I'm trying to do here is to:

- build a window for the latest X days
- on each day in this time window fetch all the transactions that happened (`transaction_summaries`, which is a view) up until that day (lots of repetition)
- fetch laterally the best historical price for the coin that day using a `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` on `historical_data`, I use a multiplication in there directly and sum it in the outer select.

This query is very expensive at the moment since I cannot find a way to either reuse calculated data or anything else.

`transaction_summaries`

```
COIN_ID | QUANTITY | TRADE_AT                | USER_ID
--------|----------|-------------------------|--------
1       | -500.0   | 2018-01-13 13:15:58     | 751
```

`historical_data`

```
ID | COIN_ID | SNAPSHOT_ON | PRICE_EUR
---|---------|-------------|----------
1  | 1       | 2017-10-07  | 0.66
2  | 2       | 2017-10-07  | 0.68
3  | 3       | 2017-10-07  | 0.13
4  | 4       | 2017-10-07  | 1.0
```

This is for a portfolio value over time for the latest 7 days, I aggregate all the transactions done up until each day and convert the quantities with the historical price's `snapshot_on` nearest the transactions' `trade_at`.

thanks for any hints.

Comment: The explain plan link leads nowhere (try http://explain.depesz.com). Is there an index on `historical_data`? `<->` is probably expensive, how about using two lateral joins to find the `max` day before and the `min` day after and then use a `CASE` expression to select the one with the smallest time difference?

Comment: What does `ORDER BY DATE(days)<->snapshot_on` clause mean ?

Comment: It is the distance operator.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe historical_data has two indexes, one unique on coin_id and snapshot_on and a Gist one on snapshot_on, I'll try to fix the PEV, thanks. I'm not sure how to proceed with your solution.

Comment: here's the explain https://explain.depesz.com/s/ctSQ

Comment: `generate_series days (cost=0.01..10.01 rows=1,000 width=8) (actual time=0.019..0.020 rows=3 loops=1)` poisons the plan. generate_series is **always** expected to give 1000 rows. Materialising it into a temp-table (*maybe* a CTE) will probably change the plan.

Comment: @wildplasser that seems a fair point, I tried but I got same results. http://tatiyants.com/pev/#/plans/plan_1520694182253
https://explain.depesz.com/s/RlTp

Comment: Did you run analyze on the temp table?

Comment: with a LIMIT in CTE seems to go better (5s instead of 9), still slow though

Comment: also: you could restrict `snapshot_on` in the subquery to (something like)  >= now() - 1 week and <= now()

Comment: @wildplasser https://explain.depesz.com/s/qNNg if you mean to see this

`EXPLAIN (ANALYZE) SELECT GENERATE_SERIES (CURRENT_DATE - '2 DAY' :: INTERVAL, CURRENT_DATE, '1 DAY' :: INTERVAL) as day LIMIT 2`

Comment: @wildplasser uhm, limiting snapshot_on seems to return very fast, I'm going to test it further!

Comment: BTW, I think you need `LIMIT 3` (not 2) on the generate_series()

Comment: @wildplasser mm, I put a `days` variable in the sql string that replaces also the LIMIT and seems ok (a value of 7 returns the latest 7 days) https://www.pastiebin.com/5aa40492187c8

Comment: @wildplasser mm, I think you're right, put +1 and started seeing today too, thanks

Comment: My idea is to use `CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT ..., days::date FROM historical_data
        WHERE ... AND days < snapshot_on 
        ORDER BY days DESC LIMIT 1) q1 CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT ..., days::date FROM historical_data
        WHERE ... AND days >= snapshot_on 
        ORDER BY days ASC LIMIT 1) q2` and use a `CASE` expression to use the values from `q1` or `q2` depending on which date is closer. That can use a B-tree index and might be faster.